# can't find a way to forward in iptables for specific mac address

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, nat, forwarding

I use a linux Centos 6.3 as an Internet gateway with NAT.
I want to allow a specific host to have access to Internet, but I don't want to use its IP address since it may get a new IP address from the DHCP server. Instead I want to use a rule for a specific MAC address.

I used the following but it does not work:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $INTERNETDEVICE -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A INPUT -i $INTERNETDEVICE -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.1.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source {my mac address} -j ACCEPT
```

where INTERNETDEVICE is the ppp device to internet

If instead of 4th rule I enter

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.1.1.39 -j ACCEPT
```

it works perfectly. But with the mac-address, it does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (Not a solution to your problem necessarily, but if this isn't a particularly security-conscious environment you could just set your DHCP server to always give the same address to your MAC, and then use that IP in the firewall)

Comment: @nickgrim Why not? It's what the rest of us do.

Comment: Well, if your machine is not on, a Malicious Attacker could set their IP statically to whatever-your-usual-IP-is, and access whatever resource it is they're not supposed to be able to access. So, not good for security-conscious environments. (Although, yeah, you can fake MACs too)

Answer (score 2):

Found similar problem [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/iptables-mac-forward-331813/).

Solution was to add this rule to your chain:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED -s 0/0 -j ACCEPT
```

Another thing was to verify that the module `ipt_mac` is loaded.